# Is there any way to get How many times the app is deleted using flurry in iOS?

Tags: ios, flurry

I am using flurry in my iOS app.
I am trying to log an event when the app is deleted by user using.
please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can log an event for any action that a user takes inside an app. It will not be possible to track deletion if a user has already exited your app. (Disclaimer: I work in the Support team at Flurry)